# How to setup ansible playbook that is able to execute kubectl (kubernetes) commands

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to write simple ansible playbook that would be able to execute some arbitrary command against the pod (container) running in kubernetes cluster.

I would like to utilise kubectl connection plugin: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/kubectl.html but having struggle to figure out how to actually do that.

Couple of questions:

1. Do I need to first have inventory for k8s defined? Something like: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/k8s.html. My understanding is that I would define kube config via inventory which would be used by the kubectl plugin to actually connect to the pods to perform specific action.
2. If yes, is there any example of arbitrary command executed via kubectl plugin (but not via shell plugin that invokes kubectl on some remote machine - this is not what I'm looking for)

I'm assuming that, during the ansible-playbook invocation, I would point to k8s inventory.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the [k8s modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_clustering_modules.html#k8s)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. While I'm able to execute some arbitrary k8s command like creating/deleting namespace or some other k8s object (using this plugin in Ansible), I don't see a way to actually connect to the specific pod/container in order to execute specific command inside the actual pod/container. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can't you do that using the dynamic inventory like on any other host ?

Comment: You almost never want to execute commands inside pods – if a node gets restarted and a pod gets rescheduled, your hand-run setup command won't get re-run.  (Or if a HorizontalPodAutoscaler creates a new pod in response to load, or...)  It's better to create a pod that can run totally autonomously.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to utilise kubectl connection plugin: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/kubectl.html but having struggle to figure out how to actually do that.

The [fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/connection.html#using-connection-plugins) describes how one uses connection plugins, and while it is [possible to use in in tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task), that is unlikely to make any sense unless your inventory *started* with Pods.

The way I have seen that connection used is to start by identifying the Pods against which you might want to take action, and then run a playbook against a unique group for that purpose:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      # this is *just an example for brevity*
      # in reality you would use `k8s:` or `kubectl get -o name pods -l my-selector=my-value` to get the pod names
      pod_names:
      - nginx-12345
      - nginx-3456
  - add_host:
      name: '{{ item }}'
      groups:
      - my-pods
    with_items: '{{ pod_names }}'

- hosts: my-pods
  connection: kubectl
  tasks:
  # and now you are off to the races
  - command: ps -ef
  # watch out if the Pod doesn't have a working python installed
  # as you will have to use raw: instead
  # (and, of course, disable "gather_facts: no")
  - raw: ps -ef
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've tried to use it but getting following error: fatal: [action-proxy-56b589f68b-cjxvp]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". ...
I think this is somewhat default error not tied to not specifying kube config since it is located on the machine from which I'm executing ansible playbook

Comment: Yes, you'll have to specify the `kubectl` related ansible vars as described [in the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/connection/kubectl.html#parameters) -- it can't _guess_ what you mean. You can either specify them in the `vars:` of that playbook (if all the pods are exactly identical), or you can specify them when executing the `add_host:` to have them carried as `hostvars`

Comment: @BakirJusufbegovic how does your inventory file looks?

Answer (score 1):

First install k8s collections

```
ansible-galaxy collection install community.kubernetes
```

and here is play-book, it will sort all pods and run a command in every pod

```
---
- 
  hosts: localhost

  vars_files: 
    - vars/main.yaml 

  collections:
    - community.kubernetes    

  tasks:     
    -
      name: Get the pods in the specific namespace
      k8s_info:
        kubeconfig: '{{ k8s_kubeconfig }}'
        kind: Pod
        namespace: test
      register: pod_list


    - 
      name: Print pod names
      debug:
         msg: "pod_list: {{ pod_list | json_query('resources[*].status.podIP')  }} "

    - set_fact:
        pod_names: "{{pod_list|json_query('resources[*].metadata.name')}}"

    - 
      k8s_exec:
        kubeconfig: '{{ k8s_kubeconfig }}'
        namespace: "{{ namespace  }}"
        pod: "{{ item.metadata.name }}"
        command: apt update
      with_items: "{{ pod_list.resources }}"
      register: exec
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.metadata.name }}"
```

Comment: how to execute a group of YAMLs?    Like we usually do here: kubectl apply -f metrics-server-0.3.6/deploy/1.8+/  ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use like this...

```
 - shell: |

     kubectl exec -i -n {{ namespace }} {{ pod_name }} -- bash -c 'clickhouse-client --query "INSERT INTO customer FORMAT CSV"
 --user=test --password=test < /mnt/azure/azure/test/test.tbl'
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [latest documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_module.html) you can use the following k8s modules

The following are some of the examples

```
- name: Create a k8s namespace
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
    name: testing
    api_version: v1
    kind: Namespace
    state: present

- name: Create a Service object from an inline definition
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
    state: present
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Service
      metadata:
        name: web
        namespace: testing
        labels:
          app: galaxy
          service: web
      spec:
        selector:
          app: galaxy
          service: web
        ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          targetPort: 8000
          name: port-8000-tcp
          port: 8000

- name: Remove an existing Service object
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
    state: absent
    api_version: v1
    kind: Service
    namespace: testing
    name: web
```