# Remove all NOT READY pods in kubernetes via ansible k8s module

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

Requirement is to do following in ansible

```sh
kubectl get pods -n default | grep "0/1" | awk {'print $1'} | xargs kubectl delete pod -n default --force --grace-period=0
```

To explain what is happening here -

- Getting all the pods in default namespace
- Grepping the ones which are in NOT READY state
- Getting only the first column i.e. the name of the pods
- Finally deleting those PODs forcefully using `kubectl delete` command

Solution I have tried
cron-job.yaml

```yaml
- name: remove dev not ready pods
  hosts: localhost
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: true
  vars:
    env: "dev"
  roles:
    - { role: k8s-app-cron,            tags: [ 'k8s-app-cron'   ]  }
```

main.yaml in role `k8s-app-cron`

```yaml
---
- name: get list of pods and remove the not ready ones
  shell: "noOfPODs=`kubectl get pods -n {{item}} | grep 0/1 | wc -l`; if [ $noOfPODs -gt 0 ]; then kubectl get pods -n {{item}} | grep 0/1 | awk {'print $1'}  | xargs kubectl delete pod -n {{item}} --force --grace-period=0; else echo 'No Pods in NOT READY state'; fi"

#  no_log: false
  environment:
    KUBECONFIG: "./_kubeconfig/{{ env }}/kubeconfig"
  register: result
  loop:
    - default
    - front
    - back
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I am planning to use `k8s_info` i came across in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718310/how-to-setup-ansible-playbook-that-is-able-to-execute-kubectl-kubernetes-comma) for different question to get the list of pods which are not ready. And then use `k8s` to make their state ABSENT. Not sure if this is the best approach though. Wanted to get hints on the best approach. @Zeitounator

Comment: This info should go in you question ([edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62466664/edit)), not in a comment. Moreover, you'll get a better chance to get a meaningful response if you actually make some sort of POC and ask question about the exact coding problems you are facing.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zeitounator, yeah makes sense. I will try it and post. Appreciate your response.

Comment: @Zeitounator, any thoughts on this implementation. Its working but i feel its not using ansible modules to their full capacity :)

Comment: You were talking about using the `k8s_info` module which I don't see there. Unless it does not meet your needs, using `shell` instead of a dedicated module is generally a bad practice. What prevents your from using it ?

Comment: @Zeitounator, I agree. I changed the shell command to make it more usable.I changed because -  Firstly - The shell command is really concise and does the job in just one task. Secondly - I can get the list of pods in NOT READY state using `k8s_info` (1 or 2 tasks req to register them as well). Now to delete them if its possible using `k8s` (I am not sure if we can delete only specific resource types with names given), i will need to use at least 2 more tasks. So 4 in total which i feel is too much work.    What do you think  :P ?